# Sybase - Filter records with current date efficiently

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to filter records based on current date (date part only) against a column "date_sent" which is a DateTime datatype. Though this can be written in multiple ways, I want to know which method will be the most efficient. The table has 11-12 millions of records ant any given time.

Let's say the current date is 16th April 2018

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE datepart(YEAR, date_sent) = 2018
  AND datepart(MONTH,date_sent) = 4
  AND datepart(DAY,date_sent) = 16;
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE convert(char(8), date_sent, 112) = convert(char(8), getdate(), 112);
```

Any other suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for formatting @an33sh

Answer (score 1):

I would start with:

```
select *
from table_name
where date_sent >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) and
      date_sent < dateadd(day, 1 + datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

The right hand side removes the time component of the current date.  The comparisons should allow Sybase to still us an index on `date_sent`.

EDIT:

Perhaps Sybase doesn't permit `0` as a date value.  You can also do:

```
select *
from table_name
where date_sent >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, cast('2000-01-01' as date), getdate()), cast('2000-01-01' as date)) and
      date_sent < dateadd(day, 1 + datediff(day, cast('2000-01-01' as date), getdate()), cast('2000-01-01' as date))
```

Comment: The dateadd and datediff functions are giving an error, wrong number or type of arguments. I am not concerned about it, as I got thinking in a different direction with your suggestion."select *
from table_name where datediff(day, date_sent, getdate()) = 0"This is giving me desired results. Do you think that will index date_sent ?

Comment: No, using `date_sent` as an argument to `datediff()` will not use an index on the column.